# iOS - The applications initial ViewController instance

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, instance, segue

Is there any way to access this without creating a new instance? As I want to perform a segue using:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:sender];
```

However if I try and create an instance, the compiler says that the segue doesn't exist. The reason I have to create a new instance is because I'm calling a method of the ViewController class from another class. Is there a way to run the method from the instance that is created in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you creating `UIViewController` instance using `[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]` method? If you instantiate with alloc-init, it will not instantiate the instance from storyboard, so it will not connect to the segue.

Here is reference to UIStoryboard class.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I am never personally creating it. I'm using storyboard like you said. Is there a way to access the instance that it creates?

Comment: There is, but unfortunately it is not very convenient. You have to traverse the the viewcontroller hierarchy from UIApplicateDelegate.window one by one. e.g, [self.window.rootViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] if you are accessing the first item in the tab bar controller that is set as the root view controller of the self.window of ApplicationDelegate.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you said 'initial viewcontroller in the title. Initial viewcontroller is the rootviewcontroller of the window, so appDelegate.window.rootViewControlller would do.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the first instance created, not initial. I think what you have said will work. I'll let you know either way.

Comment: Okay, I have an initial 'logon screen' which then pushes to the tab bar controller view. I am trying to programatically perform the segue that pushed from the logon to the tab-bar controller. How would I transverse this layout as you mentioned?

Comment: Assuming that tab-bar controller is presented as modal view controller, it is going to be `appDelegate.window.rootViewController.modalViewController` to get to the tab bar controller. You have to note that you can trace like this only after tab-bar controller was pushed (presented). Storyboard creates/deletes view controllers on demand (it is not like that Storyboard create all view controllers at launch and delete them at the exit), so the tab bar controller instance is non-existent until you perform the segue to push (present) the tab bar controller. Same wise, non-existent after dismissal.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the first instance ever created of this object to a static variable, and define a static method to access that.

```
static MyViewController *sharedInstance = nil;

@implementation MyViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
  ... init code here ...

  if (!sharedInstance) {
    sharedInstance = self;
  }

  return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
  ... init code here ...

  if (!sharedInstance) {
    sharedInstance = self;
  }

  return self;
}

+ (MyViewController *)sharedInstance
{
  if (!sharedInstance)
    [[[self alloc] init] autorelease]; // will be retained inside the init method

  return sharedInstance;
}

@end
```

Then, anywhere else in your app you can access that variable using:

```
[MyViewController sharedInsatnce];
```

It's not a very commonly used pattern, and has a few drawbacks (eg: it will never be deallocated. so make sure it doesn't use too much memory), but several classes in UIKit/Foundation use it (NSFileManager, NSUserDefaults, NSBundle, etc).